# C# Cannot create an instance because Type.ContainsGenericParameters is true

Tags: c#, .net, generics, reflection

I'm attempting to deserialize a `Generic<T> where T : struct` but when I call `ctor.Invoke(args);`  I get the exception "Cannot create an instance because Type.ContainsGenericParameters is true".

How do I pass the generic type I want it to be?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

[`Type.MakeGenericType`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.type.makegenerictype.aspx) is probably what you are looking for...

Answer (score 4):

You have to create a concrete type first using the MakeGenericType method on your generic type

Answer (score 4):

Let's say you have a `Type t` of a generic class which has a parameter-less constructor, and an array of the types to use as the type parameters of the generic class:

```
Type t = someType;
Type[] genericTypeParameters = someArrayOfTypeParameters;
```

Call [`Type.MakeGenericType()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.type.makegenerictype.aspx), which

> Substitutes the elements of an array of types for the type parameters
>   of the current generic type definition and returns a Type object
>   representing the resulting... type

Then construct the object as normal:

```
    t = t.MakeGenericType(genericTypeParameters);

    object instance = Activator.CreateInstance(t);
```